# Where is Agent Job History saved in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Where is agent job history saved in SQL Server.

I got agent job **Jxxxxxx7A392AA9-8428-4BA3-B1CD-CB3B786CD7D0**

on failure this is the history in Log File Viewer.  Where is this saved in MSDB (which table).

```
Date        20/01/2011 10:30:02 AM
Log     Job History (Jxxxxxx7A392AA9-8428-4BA3-B1CD-CB3B786CD7D0)

Step ID     1
Server      HTS0470
Job Name        Jxxxxxx7A392AA9-8428-4BA3-B1CD-CB3B786CD7D0
Step Name       Register Job
Duration        00:00:03
Sql Severity        0
Sql Message ID      0
Operator Emailed        
Operator Net sent       
Operator Paged      
Retries Attempted       0
```

Message

> Executed as user:
>   Hxxx\HSSSQLAPPService. Microsoft
>   (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>   Version 10.0.2531.0 for 64-bit 
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp
>   1984-2005. All rights reserved.
>   Started:  10:30:02 AM  DTExec: Could
>   not set
>   \Package.Variables[User::jobType].Properties[Value]
>   value to M.  Started:  10:30:02 AM 
>   Finished: 10:30:04 AM  Elapsed:  1.953
>   seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[sysjobhistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx). Note (from the MSDN link)

> Data is updated only after the jobstep completes.

Answer (score 4):

Need to take into account that the jobs history is not kept for ever, but it depends on how it's configured your SQL Agent.
You can see how much history it keeps on SQL Agent - properties - history.
So if your jobs will run and create new history records, you will lose current data.